# Shorewall to protect interfaces that are not yet defined

Tags: iptables, openvpn, netfilter, shorewall

I am planning to use Shorewall to filter traffic that originates from a virtual interface created by OpenVPN (lets call it tap0).  If OpenVPN did not successfully create this interface before Shorewall started, but the interface was defined in `/etc/shorewall/interfaces`, would traffic be filtered if the interface was successfully created later?  Would this depend on a script hook, or does Shorewall pre-create rules for interfaces that are defined in the configuration, but do not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorewall is a tool for configuring iptables/netfilter firewall rules, so the documentation for netfilter is a more effective place to look.  [It says](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html):

> It is perfectly legal to specify an interface that currently does not exist; the rule will not match anything until the interface comes up. This is extremely useful for dial-up PPP links (usually interface ppp0) and the like.
>
> As a special case, an interface name ending with a `+' will match all interfaces (whether they currently exist or not) which begin with that string. For example, to specify a rule which matches all PPP interfaces, the -i ppp+ option would be used.

Upon cursory inspection, running Shorewall with interfaces that do not exists *seems* to create `-i` and `-o` rules, which would work.

This setup would cause problems with features which require knowledge of ip/routing information to function, such as routefilter.